# Mesh won't export

Tags: mesh, export

Okay so weird problem, I'm trying to use PDX to export a mesh, for a mod I'm working on, but for some dang reason everytime I try to export the model I'm showed a response that Base Color isn't found and that confuses me, what the heck would that even mean in this situation? I am attempting to export it as a diffused mesh, and I did create the material through PDX as I'm told that's the only way you can export it
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/giujb9qrhou13/Iron_Golem
that link has my model, texture, and error that I recieved whenever I attempted to export.

Comment: According to github's site for the PDX export, this was written for blender 2.83+ but I doubt it will run on 3.1.
<https://github.com/ross-g/io_pdx_mesh>

Comment: Oh it actually runs pretty well, at least in my experience when it comes to animation files, and I have exported meshes before, at least one basic mesh file, but the problem lies that when it came to diffused, the only other thing that was different from prior exports, it just wouldn't work

Comment: Tried it on macOS with blender 3.1 and could not see export errors.